# Element of group ring not invertible, but invertible in bigger group ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, group-rings

I have thought about such problems:

- Is there a field $F$ and a group $G$ such that there exists element $x$ of group ring $FG$ which is not invertible in $FG$, but is invertible in $KG$, where $K$ is some field extension of $F$?
- A more particular version of my question is this: is it known for some $F$ being not algebraically closed and $K$ being algebraic closure of $F$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite?

Comment: @AnginaSeng both finite and infinite G find I interesting.

Comment: There are easier proofs for finite $G$; basically dimension-counting.

Comment: If $G$ is finite and its its order is prime to the characteristic of $F$, using the fact that $FG$ is semisimple+Wedderburn's thm) , we are reduced to the case of matrix algebras over a division algebra whose center is an extension of $F$. Using reduced norms, we can conclude that there is no example. Hence if $F$ and $G$ exists, then you have to be in bad characteristic.

Comment: If $G$ is finite, $F[G]$ is already Artinian, where every element is a unit or zero divisor. Extending scalars won’t be able to turn zero divisors into units, so there is no example with $G$ finite.